# PHP script header type image destroys session

Tags: php, image, session, request

I'm trying to write a small PHP script that uses a session to store a folder structure of images. Every time the side gets called it reads the next image out of session list and display it as content type of the side. When I call my script I sometimes get not the next image out of list but the next but one. When I write an output file to register every page request, I see that there were more than just one request. But if I look to my fire bug time line I don't see more than one request and there is no javascript running. If I show the image as part of an normal HTML page everything works gread. So what is going on here.

Would be nice if somebody can help me with this...

```
<?php
include("readDir.class.php");

define("IMAGE_SOURCE_PATH","img");

session_start();

//Inititalize new session context
try
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
        initSessionConext();
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    exit();
}

$fotos = $_SESSION['fotos'];

//Handle wrapp around
try
{
    if($_SESSION['id'] >= count($fotos))
        initSessionConext();
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    exit();
}
$foto = $fotos[$_SESSION['id']];
if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],"get") == 0)
     $_SESSION['id'] += 1;

//Error in session context return nothing
if(empty($foto))
    exit(); //

switch(readDir::extension($foto))
{
    case "png":
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        break;
    case "jpg": //Fall through to jpeg case
    case "jpeg":
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        break;
}

$fp = fopen("test.txt","a");
fwrite($fp,$foto."\r\n");
fclose($fp);

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
readfile(IMAGE_SOURCE_PATH."/".$foto);

//echo $foto."<br>";
//echo '<img src="'.IMAGE_SOURCE_PATH."/".$foto.'" />';

//--------------- F U N C T I O N S -------------------------------

function initSessionConext()
{
    $_SESSION['id'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['fotos'] = getNewData(IMAGE_SOURCE_PATH);
}

function getNewData($path)
{
    $extensions = array("jpg","png","jpeg");        //get data out of file system
    $fotos = array();
    $source = new readDir($path);
    if(!$source->check())
         throw new Exception('Could not find source for given path');
    $fotos = $source -> readFilesWithextension($extensions);
    if(!sort($fotos,SORT_STRING))
         throw new Exception('Could not sort foto list in natural order');
    return $fotos;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you're returning each image, one per time the image is loaded?

It seems likely to me that the browser is requesting the image twice: Once as a HEAD request, and the second time to get the content. This is commonly used to find out things like the `Content-Length` header before blindly downloading.

I would suggest making sure that `strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],"get") == 0` before modifying the session.

Comment: Thanks for your advice sounds likely for me too. But it isn't working correctly after this modification. Changed my code in the question. It works better now but sometimes it shows an image twice ore skips one.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't solve the request problem at least. Use now time difference to differ between requests. Not nice but works out of the box...